# What types of feels are there for drumming?

Tags: rhythm, drums

Playing as strictly a metal or hard rock drummer, I am only aware of a swing feel (accenting every other hi-hat note), or a straight feel (this would be more of a flat, driving beat.  More monotonous).

What other feels are there?  I imagine these might be like presets you can find on cheaper keyboards, like samba, etc.  Am I way off in this?

Comment: Swing is a lot more than merely what you portray. Are you asking for a list?

Comment: A list would be great.

Comment: I see that a list could not be reasonably comprehensive.  Maybe some popular ones?

Comment: I have a feeling that expecting a list is asking for this to be closed.

Comment: If not a list, then maybe some advice where to find this information. e.g. is it on the web, in a book?

Comment: Seems you're asking more about different *rhythms* rather than *feels*.

Comment: Swing in my mind is a feel, not a particular rhythm.

Answer (score 2):

To me, samba is a specific rhythm, which is not the same as a feel. There are hundreds of popular rhythms and there are probably thousands of feels. Even in the metal world, you might play the same rhythm with a dragging, somber feel or with an aggressive, angry feel.

To me, a feel is created by micro adjustments in timing and note emphasis (dynamics), sometimes combined with other elements like ghost notes and exactly how the kit pieces are played.

So you could play with a samba feel without playing a samba rhythm, which might mean taking the subtle timing and emphasis used when playing samba and mashing it together with a non-samba beat.